# fail2ban receiving events but not triggering event

Tags: fail2ban

I have setup fail2ban to monitor a service which I have exposed outside my router. The files are being logged properly, and the events are being picked up by fail2ban

```
2013-11-21 01:05:24,573 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Got event: 1 for /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:24,576 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  File changed: /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:34,636 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Got event: 1 for /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:34,639 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  File changed: /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:36,667 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Got event: 1 for /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:36,671 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  File changed: /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:39,700 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Got event: 1 for /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:39,703 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  File changed: /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:41,732 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Got event: 1 for /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:41,736 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  File changed: /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:48,770 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  Got event: 1 for /path/to/log.log
2013-11-21 01:05:48,773 fail2ban.filter : DEBUG  File changed: /path/to/log.log
```

jail.conf:

```
[service-name]

enabled  = true
port     = 1234
filter   = service-name
action   = iptables[name=service-name, port=1234, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=service-name, dest=user@domain.com]
logpath  = /path/to/log.log
maxretry = 5
```

fail2ban/filter.d/service-name:

```
[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf


[Definition]
_daemon = service-name

failregex = .* Login failed from <HOST>
```

Sample log file:

```
[11-21-2013 00:12:00] Login failed from 192.168.1.2
[11-21-2013 01:01:23] Login failed from 192.168.1.2
[11-21-2013 01:01:33] Login failed from 192.168.1.2
[11-21-2013 01:01:35] Login failed from 192.168.1.2
[11-21-2013 01:01:38] Login failed from 192.168.1.2
[11-21-2013 01:01:39] Login failed from 192.168.1.2
[11-21-2013 01:01:47] Login failed from 192.168.1.2
```

Any ideas where to start?

Edit:
I enabled SSH in the jail.conf and it worked with no issue, so fail2ban and iptables appears to be working right, but service is not.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same behavior and found out that the fail2ban server had incorrect time.

Comment: Did you determine why having the wrong time caused fail2ban to not work?  How much time difference can it tolerate?  Does it matter which server is in the future and which is in the past?